Default Constructor when inheriting
This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does.
class Bicycle {
    int cadence;
    int gear;
    int speed;

    public void setCadence(int newValue) {
        cadence = newValue;
    }
    
    public void setGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
    }
    
    public void applyBrake(int decrement) {
        speed -= decrement;
    }
    
    public void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed += increment;
    }
};

class MountainBike extends Bicycle {
    public int seatHeight;

    public void setSeatHeight(int newValue) {
        seatHeight = newValue;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MountainBike m1 = new MountainBike();
    }
};

Is this code depicts what have been those line saying. if yes then why is it working ? is should fail right? because, when compiler create default constructor for child class and calls default constructor of parent class, there is not constructor declared in parent class.

Java Language Specification 8.8.9. Default Constructor: "If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared." - actually the "default constructor" is exactly the one created if none is explicitly declared (not to be confused with no-argument constructor)

( the "default constructor" is a "no-argument constructor", but the "no-argument constructor" can also be a declared {coded} constructor )

The parent class gets a default constructor too (there being no explicit one).
